# How to have google links and face?

Tags: php, search, xhtml, search-engine

I've been noticing these links, faces and extra info on certain Google searches, and I would like to know how I could implement them to my site as well. I don't really know how that is even called, so sorry if I've put the wrong tags for this.

Also a side question: the photos look professional, but I have no camera, so instead of a photo, I would put a logo - would that be overstepping?

[image]

Comment: You can use the schema creator tool at schema-creator.org website and create your unique rich snipped.
and then check the results with google tool at http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the Google article on how to add your face to website search results: [Author information in search results](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986)

You can add the following code:

```
<a href="[profile_url]?rel=author">Google</a>
```

Example:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/109412257237874861202?rel=author">Google</a>
```

Alternatively, you can also do the following:

> Check that you have a email address (for example, levy@wired.com) on the same domain as your content (wired.com).
>   Make sure that each article or post you publish on that domain has a clear byline identifying you as the author (for example, "By Steven Levy" or "Author: Steven Levy").
>   Visit the Authorship page and submit your email address to Google. No matter how many articles or posts you publish on this domain, you only need to do this process once. Your email will appear in the Contributor to section of your Google+ profile. If you want to keep your email private, change the visibility of your link.
>   To see what author data Google can extract from your page, use the rich snippets testing tool.